# How to fix Multiple cascade paths in my project

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am trying to build database but i get this error all the time
"Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Characters_Item_OffHandWeaponId' on table 'Characters' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints."

These are my entities

```
  public class Item
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string? Name { get; set; }
      public string? Description { get; set; }
      public int Damage { get; set; }
      public int Armor { get; set; }
      public int Intelect { get; set; }
      public int Agility { get; set; }
      public int Strength { get; set; }
      public int Luck { get; set; }
      public int Healing { get; set; }
      [EnumDataType(typeof(ItemType))]
      public ItemType ItemType { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<Inventory>? Inventories { get; set; }

  }
```

```
   public class PlayerCharacter
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }

       public int CharacterClassId { get; set; }
       public virtual CharacterClass CharacterClass { get; set; }

       public int CharacterRaceId { get; set; }
       public virtual CharacterRace CharacterRace { get; set; }

       public virtual Inventory Inventory { get; set; }

       public virtual ICollection<EquipedJewelery> Jewelery { get; set; }


       [ForeignKey(nameof(MainHandWeapon))]
       public int? MainHandWeaponId { get; set; }
       public virtual Item MainHandWeapon { get; set; }

       [ForeignKey(nameof(OffHandWeapon))]
       public int? OffHandWeaponId { get; set; }
       public virtual Item OffHandWeapon { get; set; }

       public int UserId { get; set; }
       public virtual User User { get; set; }

       public string? Name { get; set; }
       public int Level { get; set; }
       public int Intelect { get; set; }
       public int Agility { get; set; }
       public int Strength { get; set; }
       public int Luck { get; set; }
       public int Expirience { get; set; }
       public int FinishedDungeonIndex { get; set; }
   }
```

```
    public class EquipedJewelery
    {

        public int? PlayerCharacterId { get; set; }

        public int? ItemId { get; set; }



    }
```

```
 public class Inventory
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public int PlayerCharacterId { get; set; }
     public virtual PlayerCharacter PlayerCharacter { get; set; }

     public int EnemyId { get; set; }
     public virtual Enemy Enemy { get; set; }

     public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

 }
```

```
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

public DbSet<PlayerCharacter> Characters { get; set; }
public DbSet<CharacterRace> Races { get; set; }
public DbSet<CharacterClass> Classes { get; set; }
public DbSet<Ability> Abilities { get; set; }
public DbSet<Enemy> Enemies { get; set; }
public DbSet<EnemyDungeon> EnemyDungeons { get; set; }
public DbSet<PuzzleDungeon> PuzzleDungeons { get; set; }
public DbSet<ShopDungeon> ShopDungeons { get; set; }
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
public DbSet<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
public DbSet<Inventory> Inventories { get; set; }
public DbSet<EquipedJewelery> EquipedJeweleries { get; set; }


protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<EquipedJewelery>()
        .HasKey(ej => new {ej.PlayerCharacterId, ej.ItemId});

    modelBuilder.Entity<PlayerCharacter>()
        .HasOne(c => c.OffHandWeapon)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.OffHandWeaponId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

    modelBuilder.Entity<PlayerCharacter>()
        .HasOne(c => c.MainHandWeapon)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.MainHandWeaponId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Item>() // This is the lattest addition to migration
        .HasMany<PlayerCharacter>()
        .WithOne()
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

}
```

Relations - I imagined like this:

PlayerCharacter has 1 Inventory with many items.
Each PlayerCharacter has 1 individual Inventory but can have the same items inside.

PlayerCharacter Can have 1 MainHandWeapon and 1 OffHandWeapon but again a weapon can have many PlayerCharacters.

PlayerCharacter Can have many jeweleries and everyjewelery can have many players.

After consulting with my teacher the conclusion was to delete Entities like :
potion, jewelery, weapon, Shield and just create a entity called Item.

Migration seems to build fine but I can't build database. Maybe I should totaly change relationships between entities or there is an easy fix?

i Tried adding ON DELETE NO ACTION but it did nothing and even made the problem worse I think, after adding this and rebuilding newest migration looks like this.

```
  protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
  {
      migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
          name: "ItemId",
          table: "Characters",
          type: "int",
          nullable: true);

      migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
          name: "IX_Characters_ItemId",
          table: "Characters",
          column: "ItemId");

      migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
          name: "FK_Characters_Item_ItemId",
          table: "Characters",
          column: "ItemId",
          principalTable: "Item",
          principalColumn: "Id");
  }
```

which looks kinda sus...

Somewhere here i saw a post that changing type to nullable gets rid of this problem but it doesn't work either.